# htaccess: How to remove php extension EXCEPT for index.php?param=

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to have these rules:

1. /string-smth matches index.php?param=string-smth
2. /some-file-with-dashes matches
   some-file-with-dashes.php
3. /some-file-with-dashes.php remove .php extension
   extension
4. index.php redirects to /

This works on my local machine but not on the server. Are there some options/flags or other things for apache config perhaps that need to be changed to support this?

This is my current .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

On my local machine this works, except for rule #3 (which I have not implemented in .htaccess)

On my server (digital ocean, ubuntu):

- https://karta-hrvatske.com.hr/zagreb is matched (rule #1)
- https://karta-hrvatske.com.hr/auto-karta-hrvatske.php opens the file
- https://karta-hrvatske.com.hr/auto-karta-hrvatske responses with 404

Comment: `^(.*?)$` why is there a `?` here?

Comment: tweak this: `^(.*)$ /index.php`

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the 2. rule. Is there a way to remove the ".php" when /auto-karta-hrvatske.php  is accessed directly (rule #3)?

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

So, the part of the answer is in the fix @Martin suggested.

And for the rest:

```
# remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index|url)\.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302]

# match .php if exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```